# Appium: switch from native to flutter in iOS show error "No such context found."

Tags: java, flutter, automation, appium

I'm working with appium on app switch between native and flutter component shown error, all steps in native works fine, although switch to flutter shown error 'No such context found.'

```html
public void switchContextTo(String context){
            if (context.toLowerCase().equals(FLUTTER.toLowerCase())) {
                driver.context(FLUTTER); 
            } else {
                driver.context(NATIVE_APP);
            }
        }
```

and using the function in step

```html
switchContextTo(FLUTTER);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fOZk.jpg)